# Access logged-in user info when `baseCpUrl` is different than `siteUrl`

Tags: users, control-panel, current-user

Our site's control panel needs to be on a subdomain for security purposes. So our `baseCpUrl` setting in our `general.php` file is `http://craft-admin.domain.com/` while our `siteUrl` is set at `http://www.domain.com/`.

I'm not able to access user information (specifically if a user is logged in and has `accessCp` permissions) on the main site. Dumping `user` information on a template is giving me `NULL`, I assume because there's no connection being made between `craft-admin.domain.com/` and `www.domain.com/`, so pages on `www.domain.com` can't tell me anything about logged-in users.

I ran into this trying to add in the [Admin Bar plugin](https://github.com/wbrowar/adminbar) so logged-in users can have quicker access to the Control Panel edit screen for a particular page if they're viewing it on the public-facing site. However, since there's no user information being passed along, the admin bar will never show up because it assumes I'm just a regular person browsing the site.

Is there something else I need to do in order to access logged-in user information on the front end if the `baseCpUrl` is different than the `siteUrl`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is you probably need to add the root `.domain.com` to the [defaultCookieDomain](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#defaultCookieDomain) config setting.